# 4 quarts low, 6 weeks after service

Tags: engine

I own a 2016 Kia Optima 1.6L LX Eco-T.  It has 127,000 miles on it, all highway.  My question is about 2 weeks ago I heard a tapping sound coming from the engine, when I stopped and checked the oil, there was none on the stick.  It took 4 qts to get to the fill line.  The next day, I took it back to the dealership that has serviced the since I bought it new and they said I need a new motor.  I questioned them on how it could have been 4 qts of oil low, since it was just in for service 6 weeks, 4950 miles, prior to this and how there is no oil leak, no smelling of burning oil or sight of the classic blue smoke out of the exhaust.  Their answers were as follows, the turbo could be bad and with technology today, you wouldn’t see or smell the oil burning. I believe they are lying and that 6 weeks ago their mechanic forgot to put new oil in the engine, when they serviced it.  Can someone else please explain how this could have possibly happened to the engine???????

Comment: Unfortunately, after 6 weeks you have little to stand on.  Had you found out the oil was 4 qts. or more low 2-3 days after the service, then you'd be looking at a solid case for them to replace the engine.  Generally the standard for oil consumption is 1 qt./1000 miles before the manufacturer considers the consumption excessive.  Note that I'm NOT saying this rate is typical, just that it's within what they consider to be normal range.  So after nearly 5K miles, your engine could have used up 4+ qts.  You should have checked it regularly.  Sorry, I think you're out of luck here.

Comment: As an aside, I have a friend, a mechanically challenged one, who had this same model and who neglected his oil until it was more than 4 qts. low.  He also had a connecting rod bearing failure and needed a new engine.  It was a lease and the sales department made is all "go away" by fixing him up with a new Kia.  He still paid for the repairs, it was just buried in the new vehicle price.

Answer (score -1):

RAther than fight about hypotheticals, just perform an oil consumption test. Change the oil and then check the dipstick once a week until the next oil change. The amount of oil used was either burned or leaked. If the amount it used is excessive, then do a compression and cylinder leakdown test to determine valve and piston ring/cylinder wall condition.

Comment: Not fighting over hypotheticals, just trying to determine if the dealership, either forgot to put oil in the engine or something else has happened to the engine since the last oil change which was 6 weeks prior to motor making a rod knock or valve tapping.

Comment: Pretty much moot at this point, don't you think?